# Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am using jwt to create token, but when i login via postman I get the error "Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value" from my console. I have attached my login code. Please anyone who can help me

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message:
            "Auth failed!! either the account does't exist or you entered a wrong account"
        });
      }
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed",
            token: token
          });
        }
        if (result) {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              email: user.email,
              password: user.id
            },
            process.env.JWT_KEY,
            {
              expiresIn: "1h"
            }
          );

          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Auth granted, welcome!",
            token: token
          });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
};
```

this is my env.json file

```
{
    "env":{
        "MYSQL":"jllgshllWEUJHGHYJkjsfjds90",
        "JWT_KEY": "secret"
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It looks like your application can't read the environment variable properly.

I don't know which package you are using to load environment variables but the simplest way is using **dotenv** package.

After installing it with npm i dotenv, import it as early as possible in your application main file like this:

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

Create .env file in your application root folder with this content ( as you see the format is key=value)

```
MYSQL=jllgshllWEUJHGHYJkjsfjds90
JWT_KEY=secret
```

Then you can access their values like you already did:

```
process.env.JWT_KEY
```

.env file:

[image]

Comment: i have installed the dotenv and required as your comment to me but still i get the same error, see the screen shot i have uploaded to my previous question

Comment: @mchomvu did you also create .env file in your root folder?

Comment: @mchomvu I added a screenshot to show how  .env file must be.

Comment: Lastly require("dotenv").config();  must be in the first lines of main file (like index.js or app.js)

Comment: yes i created an env file but as a json file, is it correct with that format?

Comment: @mchomvu no it must exactly be in the same  format I showed in the answer

Answer (score 44):

Remove the process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY and do it this way: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY}` wrap it with backtick.
It solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you. this worked for me. If your .env file is on point and you have used @nest/config, kindly use this solution.

Comment: @elonaire When using `@nestjs/config` you should use `ConfigService`, see my response.

Comment: This is not a safe solution friend! You'll end up with a secret that's "undefined" instead of what your actual secret is.

Comment: This is the correct answer.
Using dotenv library even with `openssl rand -base64 32` command to create a correct password with no problems with special characters is not enough.
You should also follow this method stated in this answer.

Comment: It only works because the the result is an empty string instead of the actual value. Using this would be totally UNSAFE!

Answer (score 21):

Had this issue with NestJS when trying to rely on `process.env.X`. Supposedly `@nestjs/config` uses `dotenv` in the background but it doesn't work as expected. I either had to use `ConfigService` or explicitly configure `dotenv` in the given files:

`jwt.strategy.ts`

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    });
  }
}
```

or

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      secretOrKey: configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
    });
  }
}
```

`auth.module.ts`

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
})
```

or

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule]
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          secret: configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
```

Comment: I think `dotenv.config()` is done behind the scenes when you use Nest.js ConfigXXX classes, happened to me when I used `process.env.JWT_XXX` that didn't get picked up in tests, since there's no `dotenv.config()` anywhere .

Answer (score 16):

It was accidentally adding the `JWTService` as a provider in my `AuthModule`. That, it seems was overriding the defaults I had set up when registering the `JWTModule`.

What I had before:

```ts
@Module({
      imports: [
        PassportModule,
        JwtModule.registerAsync({
          imports: [ConfigModule],
          inject: [ConfigService],
          useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
            const authConfig = configService.get<AuthenticationConfig>(
              PathNames.AUTH,
            );
            return {
              secret: authConfig.accessToken.secret,
              signOptions: {
                expiresIn: authConfig.accessToken.expiryTime,
              },
            };
          },
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        UsersService,
        PrismaService,
        AuthResolver,
        // this was the problem
        JwtService,
        JWTStrategy,
      ],
      exports: [AuthService],
    })
    export class AuthModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the reason why my nestjs implementation didnt work as well...

Answer (score 13):

It works for me only if I concatenate it with an empty string like this:

```
"" + process.env.JWT_KEY
```

Comment: This is not a safe solution friend! You'll end up with a secret that's "undefined" instead of what your actual secret is.

Comment: Do not use this!

This ensures the parameter for secret is always a string but if the process env does not exist, this will be converted to the string "undefined".

Answer (score 6):

simply remove the process.env.JWT_KEY and replace with "secret key using" ES6  String Literals

`${process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY}`

it solves this for me

Comment: This is not a safe solution friend! You'll end up with a secret that's "undefined" instead of what your actual secret is.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure `process.env.JWT_KEY` has a valid value? I believe it is `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: Did you `console.log` the value?

Answer (score 3):

This message was occured to me only when I was running E2E tests. In my case I had to explicitly set as an **secret** option to fix it.

```
this.jwtService.sign(tokenPayload, { secret: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}` });
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the require('dotenv').config() at the top of the server.js file
This solved for me

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, it works for me.
"" + process.env.JWT_KEY

Comment: This is not a safe solution friend! You'll end up with a secret that's "undefined" instead of what your actual secret is.

Comment: Do not use this! This ensures the parameter for secret is always a string but if the process env does not exist, this will be converted to the string "undefined".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the `JwtModule.Register` object in `auth.module.ts` and not `app.module.ts`

It looks something like the below,

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

> NOTE: For more clarity read this again https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication

Comment: This helped! I was trying to register JWTModule in AppModule as I thought it will be the initialization space for all the modules but I was wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I simply removed process.env.JWT_KEY and replace with "secret" and its working fine.

Comment: Don't do that! A secret has that name for a reason. It's not a secret anymore once you commit it to the repo.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just add back quotes `` and use the syntax `${process.env.SECRET_KEY}` in them.
2. I also advise you to use the **cross-env** package, after installing which you can make two files with environment variables .development.env and .production.env

To configure `cross-env`, just paste this into a `package.json` `"scripts"` field:

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV = production nest start",
"start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV = development nest start --watch"
```

it is for nestjs

Comment: This is not a safe solution friend! You'll end up with a secret that's "undefined" instead of what your actual secret is.

Answer (score 0):

To chime in on this, I found this error was being caused by the contents of the key I was trying to use. I regularly use a "password generator" for such strings, and it had given me the following to use:

*<B#LCK$^\7(T^fuaQemeR&6s:#@AA*we@?T,c'=+kxT?euCP27R/D=uRm893$=^_h^f={c.)MD`#[%zg}$K8_D#D-_/`tb2?Q>RFr(}H:Fp#{&yNFt@2Y<K\GB28unz

if the above is placed in between back ticks or speech marks it will not be able to be parsed as a string and will therefore cause this error as described above.

As an extra level of de-bugging make sure you first wrap your key in backticks or parenthesis in order to make sure that an un-parsable string isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and specify an object with a property the path to the configuration file like
`require("dotenv").config({path: '/path_to_env_file'});`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue I came to realize that the issue was that I didn't include dotenv package

so

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
```

then put `dotenv.config()` on top before any other implementation

Answer (score 0):

step 1: [install dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

step 2: import that in app.js:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
```

step 3:

```
dotenv.config(`${process.env.SECRET_KEY}`);
```

your issue will solve

Comment: I get the error `Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object`

Answer (score 0):

Check that `process.env.JWT_KEY` is defined:

```js
console.log(process.env.JWT_KEY)
```

Comment: And if it's not defined?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue in backend. To solve I create a *init*.js file, add my config to process.env and require index.js file

```
const config = require(`<path of config json file>`)
process.env = { ...process.env, ...config }
require('./index')
```

then get *init*.js as entry index in webpack

Answer (score 0):

Do not fix this by prepending an empty string `'' +`  to your JWT or by wrapping it inside of `${process.env.YOUR_JWT}`. This resolves the error but doesn't fix the underlying issue.

The problem is actually that dotenv is being invoked *after* your module code where you try to read from `process.env`, therefore `process.env.ANYTHING_HERE` won't have been populated by dotenv yet.

Probably in your entrypoint file (i.e. `main.ts` you are calling `import` on `app.module` before calling into dotenv or nest's wrapper around it.

The comprehensive fix here is to modify `main.ts` to call `require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' })` or however you bootstrap your env, and to do this **before** you import any other file. That way, *all* your imports will have `process.env` populated with your environment variables before they run.

If you just fix the issue by following the solutions above then you're going to end up setting your secret key to `'undefined'` because what you're actually just doing is you're concatenating empty string with the env variable for your secret before it exists. It solves the error but clearly won't be the secret you wanted from your config file.

It's also not a good idea to fix it this way because you're not solving this issue for your other environment variables either. They still won't be available to your modules where they need them because they're being included *after* instead of before, and thus you're highly likely to have other issues in your project where your environment variables are undefined elsewhere too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using `process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")` worked perfectly fine.
I took this reference from how firebase uses keys stored in .env file to parse it. and they use `.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")` to parse the key.

Answer (score 0):

As I have encountered the same problem by now, solution was simple as;

import - or NOT forget to import - :)  ConfigModule to the AppModule.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `process.env.JWT_SECRET` through backticks. It solved the problem for me.

```js
 const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, `process.env.JWT_SECRET`, {
      expiresIn: "7d",
    });
```

Comment: "process.env.JWT_SECRET" is your literal string any hacker could easily guess that and they can generate access tokens on their own.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in production when my app was deployed. The solution was quite simple for me; I forgot to set up the variable `SECRET`. Check if you properly setup the variables in env file or in your secret manager.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the .env is being imported, as mentioned above, use the library dotenv is the easiest way.

also in my case I had to add template literals `${procces.env.JWT_KEY}` and then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

IN token REPLACE GRAB THE FOLLOWING IN BACKTICKS. THIS SYNTEX WORKED FOR ME TRY THIS.

`${process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY}`

Comment: This is not a safe solution friend! You'll end up with a secret that's "undefined" instead of what your actual secret is.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you use 2 .env files (for development and for production). For example, you use `cross-env NODE_ENV=development` in package.json file in `"start:dev"`. If it is true, don't forget add

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
    envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`
}),
```

to your module file:

```
@Module({
imports: [
  PassportModule,
  ConfigModule.forRoot({
    envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`
}),
  JwtModule.register({
    secret: process.env.JWT_KEY,
    signOptions: { 
      expiresIn: '1h' 
    },
  }),
],
providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Then you haven't to add something to file with class JwtStrategy and another.

Answer (score -1):

`${process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY}`
it worked for me by placing it in *auth.module.ts*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not a safe solution friend! You'll end up with a secret that's "undefined" instead of what your actual secret is.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Use the "secret" in place of "process.env.JWT_KEY"]

Use the code above(image), to overcome your problem.

Comment: Don't do that! A secret has that name for a reason. It's not a secret anymore once you commit it to the repo.

Answer (score -2):

This error is coming because .env files is not accessible in auth.js.
so dont write process.env.JWT_KEY
instead of this just write a random string in single quotes.
eg: 'iamtheprogrammer'

ERROR:

`const token = jwt.sign({_id:user._id}, process.env.SECRET)`

CORRECT CODE:

`const token = jwt.sign({_id:user._id},'iamtryingtoaddsome')`

Comment: should be `jwt.sign({_id:user._id},{secret})` there is no overload with string as parameter for options

Comment: you should NEVER hardcode a secret, doing that is a huge security vulnerability