# The app works fine with localhost but Heroku gives bad request error when trying to login or signup with post

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, sequelize.js, heroku-postgres

I have my first node.js app (runs fine locally) - but Heroku gives Bad Request(400) error when trying to login or sign up (first time heroku as well). The code is below. I would say that the running the code locally as well within my network shows no issue. I didn't understand if the problem comes from the frontend request.

And the code:
index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const loggerMiddleWare = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const { PORT } = require("./config/constants");
const authRouter = require("./routers/auth");
const artworkRouter = require("./routers/artworks");
const bodyParserMiddleWare = express.json();
const app = express();

app.use(loggerMiddleWare("dev"));
app.use(bodyParserMiddleWare);
app.use(cors());

if (process.env.DELAY) {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    setTimeout(() => next(), parseInt(process.env.DELAY));
  });
}

app.use("/", authRouter);
app.use("/artworks", artworkRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port: ${PORT}`);
});
```

auth.js

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { Router } = require("express");
const { toJWT } = require("../auth/jwt");
const authMiddleware = require("../auth/middleware");
const User = require("../models/").user;
const { SALT_ROUNDS } = require("../config/constants");

const router = new Router();

router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(`Before const { email, password } = req.body;`);
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log(`After const { email, password } = req.body;`);

    if (!email || !password) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .send({ message: "Please provide both email and password" });
    }

    console.log(`Before await User.findOne({ where: { email } });`);
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
    console.log(`After await User.findOne({ where: { email } });`);

    if (!user || !bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: "User with that email not found or password incorrect",
      });
    }

    delete user.dataValues["password"]; // don't send back the password hash
    const token = toJWT({ userId: user.id });
    return res.status(200).json({ token, ...user.dataValues });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: `Login Page: Something went wrong, sorry: ${JSON.stringify(
        req.headers
      )}, AND, ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}
      )}`,
    });
  }
});

router.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, name, isArtist } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password || !name) {
    return res.status(400).send("Please provide an email, password and a name");
  }

  try {
    const newUser = await User.create({
      email,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, SALT_ROUNDS),
      name,
      isArtist,
    });

    delete newUser.dataValues["password"]; // don't send back the password hash

    const token = toJWT({ userId: newUser.id });

    res.status(201).json({ token, ...newUser.dataValues });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name === "SequelizeUniqueConstraintError") {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .send({ message: "There is an existing account with this email" });
    }

    return res
      .status(400)
      .send({ message: "Signup Page: Something went wrong, sorry" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

config.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    url: process.env.DB_URL,
    dialect: "postgres",
    operatorsAliases: "0",
  },
  test: {
    username: "root",
    password: null,
    database: "database_test",
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    dialect: "postgres",
    operatorsAliases: "0",
  },
  production: {
    use_env_variable: "DATABASE_URL",
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
    },
    dialect: "postgres",
  },
};
```

constants.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  SALT_ROUNDS: 10,
  PORT: process.env.PORT || 4000,
};
```

Procfile:

```
release: bash post-release.sh
```

post-release.sh:

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
```

I have also a .env file

```
DB_URL=postgres....
JWT_SECRET=....
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you share the ValidationError ?

Comment: Are you sure that DB_URL is the correct 'Heroku Postgres ENV' variable ?

Comment: From Resources tab in your project, Heroku Postgres should give you a "DATABASE_URL"

Comment: No, there is a Url that will be for heroku and it's different

Comment: Heroku will not change the DATABASE_URL unless you tell it to do or you do it manually.

Comment: Faced Same problem and find [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73233293/next-js-bad-request-when-trying-any-request-in-production/74128966#74128966)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen that there was an error in auth middleware:

> JsonWebTokenError: secret or public key must be provided.

This means my application can't read the environment variable properly.
I've fixed this problem to change `toJWT` function. It uses `jwt.sign(data, jwtSecret, { expiresIn: "1h" })` function. I've changed
`jwtSecret` as `"" + jwtSecret`
as in the succession there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62350806/15018495.