# secretOrPrivateKey must have a value (hardcoding the secret | no undefined values)

Tags: javascript, jwt, nestjs

PS : I tested these : [Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673430/error-secretorprivatekey-must-have-a-value)

I have these piece of codes that work in another project, I copy-paste them exactly as they are to another fresh project with same dependencies versions and it's showing this error.
the error occurs when I call the sign function like this :

```
await this._jwtTokenService.signAsync(user),
```

where _jwtTokenService is injected in the constructor like this :

```
  constructor(
private _jwtTokenService: JwtService,
) {}
```

I saw this error before but the fix was to inject the 'secret' in the jwtModule.register function like this :

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
    return {
      secret: 'secret',
    };
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
}), `
```

but that doesn't work now, unless I do this to the sign function

```
await this._jwtTokenService.signAsync(user, {secret : 'secret'}),
```

when I print _jwtTokenService to see what values it's inheriting, I see it has empty options object:

```
JwtService {
 options: {},
 logger: Logger { context: 'JwtService', options: {} }
  }
```

for example I tried to pass this in the register function :

```
  signOptions: { expiresIn: '30 days' },
```

it still has empty object. anything I'm doing wrong here?

```
 "dependencies": {
"@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/jwt": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
"@nestjs/microservices": "^9.1.4",
"@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.2.0",
"@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
"@nestjs/swagger": "^6.1.2",
"@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
"bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
"class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
"class-validator": "^0.13.2",
"express-session": "^1.17.3",
"mongoose": "^6.6.5",
"passport": "^0.6.0",
"passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"rimraf": "^3.0.2",
"rxjs": "^7.2.0"
 },
```

auth.module.ts

```
    @Module({
     imports: [
    UsersModule,

    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secret', //to add .env
      secretOrPrivateKey: 'secret',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '30 days' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, SessionSerializer, JwtService],
  exports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    AuthService,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule,
     ],
    })
     export class AuthModule {}
```

in auth.services.ts :

```
  async loginWithCredentials(user: UserDto) {
    const userEntity: UserDto = await this.validateUser(
      user.username,
      user.password,
    );
    const token = await this.createToken(userEntity);

    return new LoginPayloadDto(token);
  }

  async createToken(user: UserDto): Promise<TokenDto> {
    console.log(user);
    return new TokenDto({
      expiresIn: 30,
      accessToken: await this._jwtTokenService.signAsync(user),
    });
  }
```

I use the auth service in app controller  :

```
  @Post('login')
  async loginHttp(@Body() user: UserDto) {
    return this.authService.loginWithCredentials(user);
  }
```

app.module :

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: configs,
      isGlobal: true,
      cache: true,
      envFilePath: ['.env'],
      expandVariables: true,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(`mongodb://localhost:27017/admin`),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
  exports: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

ps : it does not work even if I put the config in the app module

Error I get :

```
[Nest] 84469  - 10/10/2022, 5:21:48 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/media/work/alternatives-matomo/in-auth/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:107:20)
    at /media/work/alternatives-matomo/in-auth/node_modules/@nestjs/jwt/dist/jwt.service.js:33:53
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at JwtService.signAsync (/media/work/alternatives-matomo/in-auth/node_modules/@nestjs/jwt/dist/jwt.service.js:33:16)
    at AuthService.createToken (/media/work/alternatives-matomo/in-auth/src/auth/auth.service.ts:56:48)
    at AuthService.loginWithCredentials (/media/work/alternatives-matomo/in-auth/src/auth/auth.service.ts:47:30)
    at /media/work/alternatives-matomo/in-auth/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at /media/work/alternatives-matomo/in-auth/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you show the related modules with respect to where these services are being used? This is usually a configuration issue where _somewhere_ a `JwtModule` gets imported with no options

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing JwtService from list of providers in auth.module fixed it

```
        @Module({
     imports: [
    UsersModule,

    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secret', //to add .env
      secretOrPrivateKey: 'secret',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '30 days' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, SessionSerializer],
  exports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    AuthService,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule,
     ],
    })
     export class AuthModule {}
```